# Why doesn't this network call return the image

Tags: ios, network-programming, uiimage, swift-playground

If I put this URL into a browser, the 206 KB image comes back in 2 seconds.
Why doesn't this call complete the download?
The data returned has response 200 which I thought meant that the http call had completed.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

func getImageFromURL(_ imageURL: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
  if let url = URL(string: imageURL) {
    print("Download: \(imageURL)")
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, timeoutInterval: 29.0)

    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
      guard let response = response, let data = data else {
        completion(nil)
        print("Failed to load image.")
        return
      }

      print("Image data is \(data)")
      let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(downloadedImage)
        print("Downloaded image size: \(downloadedImage?.size)")
      }
    }.resume()
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
let theUrlString: String = "http://www.impawards.com/2014/posters/american_sniper_xlg.jpg" // 206 KB image

var theImage: UIImage = UIImage()
getImageFromURL(theUrlString) { image in
  theImage = image!
}
print("theImage size: \(theImage.size)")
```

Comment: Your code is working, I have tried it in playground, if you refer to your print size it's outside the completion.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, get an image of size 539 bytes, dimensions 1x1.

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro My code doesn't retrieve the image, so to me that means it is not working. It doesn't produce an error either. The code is actually a test from a larger app where the image is used in an ImageView, and all I get is a blank rectangle. The final print of image size is outside the completion, but if you run the code there is also a print within the completion that produces the same 1,1 size details.

Comment: @AndrewCSP I understand now what you mean, try this, set your link as https and set Allow Arbitrary Loads to YES for App Transport Security Settings in your info.plist.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 for confirming its a problem! Much appreciated.

Comment: @AndrewCSP - when I run your code, I get (of course) *"App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load..."*. If I change your url string to "https: // www.impawards.com..." I *still* get the error, because the server is re-directing to a non-HTTPS connection. You can confirm this by loading the "https:// ..."  url in a browser - then check the address after the image loads. It will revert back to "http:// ..."

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the App Transport Security Setting requirement. My environment already has that set to Allow Arbitrary Loads so that is not the problem. I am trying to develop for an arbitrary URL - this one is just a working example.